# Laravel not sending email from server and not giving errors

Tags: laravel, server, localhost

I have problem,
when I send mail from localhost everything works fine,
but when send from server I don't receive mail and I don't get error.

My env. file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
```

and function

```
    protected function contactMe() {

      Mail::send('request2e', array(
        'subject' =>Input::get("subject"),
        'email' => Input::get("email"),
        'message1' => Input::get("message1"),
        'number' => Input::get("number")

    ), function ($message) {

    $message->from('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Contact');

    $message->to('yyyy@gmail.com')->subject('Contact');

});
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: do you've 2 step verification? have you set MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls ?

Comment: I set MAIL_ENCRYPTION and I have turn off 2 step verification but I got same error

Comment: the case that worked well with me was: turning 2 step on=> using [app password](https://security.google.com/settings/u/0/security/apppasswords)

Comment: and you try to use `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail`

Comment: when use mail_driver=sendmail Laravel not sending email from server and not giving errors

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gmail smtp you have to use the smtp driver:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Make sure to clear the config cache if you have to (required in production).

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Everything else seems to be aok.

In your Gmail settings page do the following:

> Click on the Forwarding/IMAP tab and scroll down to the IMAP Access section: IMAP must be enabled in order for emails to be properly copied to your sent folder.

Comment: I put MAIL_DRIVER=smtp and still don't send mail

Comment: Thanks, Now I got this error Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265:
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

Comment: Most likely your provider is blocking the port or a firewall is preventing sending through that port, try to use: `MAIL_PORT=465` and `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` if that doesn't work, consult your hosting provider.

Comment: still same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you there is a problem with [google app security functionality](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

From above given link, turn on this functionality and check for this issue.

Hope this helps you.!